# MVC 3 Entity Framework Error - Item has already been added. Key in dictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, httpcontext

I am making a MVC 3 web application using Entity Framework but I am getting this error. In my data layer I used a class connection helper.

Error is followig:

Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'DbActiveContext'  Key being added: 'DbActiveContext'

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'DbActiveContext'  Key being added: 'DbActiveContext'

Error is on Line 24:

```
Line 22:                 {
Line 23:                     _connection = new flashEntities(ConnectionString);
**Line 24:                     HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("DbActiveContext", _connection);**
Line 25:                 }
Line 26:                 return _connection;
```

my Connection helper class is as follow (Same connection helper class is working fine in another mvc 3 web application):

```
public ObjectContext Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connection == null && HttpContext.Current.Items["DbActiveContext"] != null)
            {
                _connection = (flashEntities)HttpContext.Current.Items["DbActiveContext"];
            }
            else
            {
                _connection = new flashEntities(ConnectionString);
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("DbActiveContext", _connection);
            }
            return _connection;
        }
    }
    private ObjectContext _connection;

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["flashEntities"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Is `DbActiveContext` declared anywhere else, for instance the web.config?

Comment: @Gabe: Not it just declared in connection helper class, nowhere else.

Comment: Instead of `HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("DbActiveContext", _connection);`, try `HttpContext.Current.Items["DbActiveContext"] =  _connection;` This would then just replace an existing item with the same key.

Comment: @Netricity - Then what if the key doesn't exist? Seems to be a band-aid.

Comment: @Gabe - not getting you

Comment: @Netricity - Nor the problem...

Comment: @Gabe - thanks for clarifying and not being sarcy

Comment: @Netricity: Yes its working perfectly, but what was the problem with my code? shouldn't it also ADD the item as a new? Can you please explain. Thank you so much by the way

Comment: @ArbazAbid - using the indexer it will call Add if it doesn't exist, but it will replace if it already does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is causing the line

```
 HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("DbActiveContext", _connection);
```

to execute more than once.  Take another look at your If condition.
could you be causing it to fail more than once ?  Say if _Connection was being set to null ...

Answer (score 0):

Threading could cause this. Without seeing the code that calls this it's tough to tell if that's the case here, but consider 2 threads both asking for a dbcontext. Your code is roughly:

```
1. if (!dbcontext)
    2. add dbcontext
```

Picture it as:

Thread 1 executes line 1, branches to line 2
Thread 2 executes line 1, branches to line 2
Thread 1 executes line 2, dbcontext now added
Thread 2 executes line 2, attempts to add dbcontext, asplode.

Pretty classic threading problem.

You can prevent this with a lock:

```
private object creationLock = new object();

. . .

lock(creationLock)
{
    if (...)
        add...
}
```